# Programmatically redirect to URL outside the vue-router app but on the same domain?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an external web site and vue app on the same domain. I want programmatically redirects a user from vue app to external web site with a full page reload.

**Example**

- http://example.com --> vue + vue-router App
- http://example.com/external-site --> external web site

Comment: Well u can do it with a common a tag with href? As i know for routung you use router link to get a new page without server request

Comment: I am using routes as 

{

   path:'*',
   redirect:'/404' 
}

So any link /external-site just is redirected to /404 without page reload.

Comment: `location.href = '/external-site'`

Comment: Your catch-all route won't come into play if `/external-site` is a real file / directory unless your server-side URL rewriting is misconfigured

Comment: location.href = '/external-site' does not work.Vue-router catches URL changes and prevents page reloads. 
I need to navigate from vue-app (http://example.com) to http://example.com/external-site by clicking the button inside vue app,  Also I need to catch all routes (except /external-site/*) by vue-app.
The server configuration is configured correctly. The problem is to do this redirect.

Comment: _"The server configuration is configured correctly"_  I guarantee that it is not. Can you please add the details to your question?

Comment: Phil, you're right. location.href = '/external-site' works fine and forces page to load. The problem was in server side redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 2.x, you can create a route that will go to an external URL by adding a route like this:

```
{
    path: "/Stackoverflow",
    component: Stackoverflow,
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```

Activate using:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/Stackoverflow' });
```